# Error in c# method says not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I have a function as below, it throws an error as not all code paths return a value. I am trying this first time in c#

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
    {
        if (sal <= 1000)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (sal > 1000 && sal <= 3000)
        {
            return (0.15 * sal);
        }
        if (sal > 3000)
        {
            return (0.28 * sal);
        }
    }
```

What is the issue above?

Comment: I suspect the compiler can't tell you've covered all possible values, when in fact you have. Try using `if`, `else if` then `else` instead of three independent `if` conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using standard `else if` syntax in order not to deceive the compiler

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
{
    if (sal <= 1000)
        return 0;
    else if (sal <= 3000)
        return (0.15 * sal);
    else
        return (0.28 * sal);
}
```

Comment: `sal > 1000` is superfluous, since `sal` must be > 1000 if it is not <= 1000.

Comment: i guess no need to check if its greater than 1000 in 2nd if

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: thank you! You are quite right, I shouldn't have copied and pasted the conditions from the question

Comment: @Sajeetharan: thank you! The check being copy+pased from the question is actually *redundant* in the context. You're quite right.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for the same things over and over again.

After the first if statement `sal` is always >1000

After the second it is always >3000

You can simplify your code and get rid of the error:

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
    {
        if (sal <= 1000)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (sal <= 3000)
        {
            return (0.15 * sal);
        }
        return (0.28 * sal);
    }
```

Bonus: you can make it a oneliner with chained [conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
        => sal <= 1000 ? 0 : (sal <= 3000 ? 0.15 * sal : 0.28 * sal);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the mathematical point of view, your code does always return a value; however, the C# compiler does not do a mathematical analysis of your code, but only sees that there is a sequence of 3 if-statements and deduces, that if none of them applies, then no value will be returned. C# only analyses the flow on a syntactical level, but not the content of the expressions.

You can simplify the code and at the same time ensure that C# sees a `return` in any case with:

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
{
    if (sal <= 1000) return 0;
    if (sal <= 3000) return 0.15 * sal;
    return 0.28 * sal;
}
```

Or

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
{
    return sal <= 1000 ? 0 : sal <= 3000 ? 0.15 * sal : 0.28 * sal;
}
```

Also, there is no need to test `sal > 1000` and `sal > 3000`, since if the code did not return before, then `sal` must be greater than 1000 or greater than 3000 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return at the end and simplify the conditionals.

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
    {
        if (sal > 1000 && sal <= 3000)
        {
            return (0.15 * sal);
        }
        else if (sal > 3000)
        {
            return (0.28 * sal);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps, but the C# compiler would not always try to prove all use-cases.

As it is written earlier the last if is not useful (as it is a consequence of the previous ones), but if you think that this code is changing very often, and sometimes someone would put a branch that fail, you can add instead of return a throw new Exception block

```
public static double calTotal(double sal)
{
    if (sal <= 1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (sal > 1000 && sal <= 3000)
    {
        return (0.15 * sal);
    }
    if (sal > 3000)
    {
        return (0.28 * sal);
    }
    throw new Exception ("This line of code should never be hit");
}
```

If you care about the code to be like this though, make always sure to understand that putting the code with throwing exception is a burden on generated code, and this code would run a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, the best practice should be to declare a variable, change it if any clause verify and then return it at the end

```
    public static double calTotal(double sal)
    {
        double value = 0;
        if (sal > 1000 && sal <= 3000)
        {
            value = (0.15 * sal);
        }
        if (sal > 3000)
        {
            value = (0.28 * sal);
        }
        return value;
    }
```